# Variable json list to categorical feature columns

Tags: python, json, pandas, scikit-learn

I have a json file that looks like this:

```
[
    {
        "id" : "0001"
        "label" : "A"
        "properties": [
            "a",
            "b",
            "c"
        ]
    },
    {
        "id" : "0002"
        "label" : "B"
        "properties": [
            "b", 
            "d",
            "e"
        ]

    }
]
```

This dataset is quite big, it has 20 different labels, 9000 distinct properties and tens of thousands of distinct ids.

I'm processing this file with python and want to use scikit-learn to build a model that can make predictions.

How do I go about and make sure that I end up with encoded features that look somewhat like this:

```
id,   label, a, b, c, d, e
0001, A,     1, 1, 1, 0, 0
0002, B,     0, 1, 0, 1, 1
```

I tried using pandas, patsy and a few other things but couldn't get a proper dataset out of the json. I could of course write everything manually but that would a) be much slower to process and b) doesn't give me any insight into these tools (pandas, numpy, scipy, scikit-learn)

Comment: It's not json, you should replace all ' with ", and remove redundant ","

Comment: That's a bit harsh. I was in fact json, only not valid. Anyway, fixed it.